# Are my questions on-topic here, and if so, should a few new tags be created, maybe?

Tags: support

I have a question about my Super User post: [How to mount FAT16/32 USB volume on smartos/illumos/omnios?](https://superuser.com/questions/1587427/how-to-mount-fat16-32-usb-volume-on-smartos-illumos-omnios)

Are my questions about Illumos, OmniOS, SmartOS on-topic here, and if so, should a few corresponding tags be created? I don't have enough rep to do that.

If my questions are not on-topic that much, where else might I post them? Like, elsewhere on StackExchange? unix, maybe?

Comment: A single question about these operating systems don’t seem to justify the creation of multiple tags.  At least two of those operating systems seems nearly identical.  Your question doesn’t seem isolated to those operating systems, but to Unix/Linux operating systems in general.

Comment: @Ramhound, I understand what you mean by the first part, but don't understand the last part. I'm familiar with linux. I can mount a filesystem on linux easily. The Illumos variants seem like an alien landscape in comparison. Now if you said Solaris, maybe, IDK, I'm not familiar with Solaris either. But practically everything seems different on SmartOS compared to Linux. Correct me if I'm wrong.